# How to convert any video format to mp4 format in python

Tags: python, angular7, ionic4

I am building an app in angular where customers will upload video of any format, I need to convert it into mp4 format and display on client side. I need help with how to convert any video format to mp4 in python

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly a base64 video is - simply the normal file encoded in base 64? In that case I'm sure the question has been answered already

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I have updated my question